# How flush specific type of cache

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, block-cache

I need to flush only block HTML of Magento 1,9

If I write

```
try {

Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('block_html'); 

 } catch (Exception $e) {
        die("[ERROR:" . $e->getMessage() . "]" . PHP_EOL);
 }
```

It's correct?

Comment: Accept the answer If you find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you have **Magerun n98 installed, you can do this from SSH.

All commands try to detect the current Magento root directory. If you have multiple Magento installations you must change your working directory to the preferred installation.

To view the status of the cache, enter:

`php n98-magerun.phar cache:status`

You can flush specific type of cache by entering:

`php n98-magerun.phar cache:flush [type] ... [type]`

In your case:

`php n98-magerun.phar cache:flush block_html`

Also, you can run this command if you don't have Magerun:

```
php -r 'require "app/Mage.php"; Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush(block_html);'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::CACHE_GROUP);
```

Where Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::CACHE_GROUP is `block_html` you can pass different type of cache also, like

- block_html
- collections
- config
- layout
- translate
- eav
- config_api
- config_api2